# Unable to install google-chrome-stable for docker container

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu

Hi I am trying to launch my selenium app to work on an Ubuntu server. It seems like there is an issue connecting to the mirrors and I am unable to find a solution. There is no proxy blocking connections out either.

DockerFile:

```
FROM python:latest
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install -y google-chrome-stable

RUN chmod +X /driver/chromedriver
CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]
```

Error:

```
Step 7/10 : RUN apt update -y
 ---> Running in c9fcd65e5d5a

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Err:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
  Could not connect to dl.google.com:80 (172.217.1.142). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
  Could not connect to debian.map.fastlydns.net:80 (151.101.50.132). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (151.101.66.132). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (151.101.130.132). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (151.101.194.132). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (151.101.2.132). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
  Could not connect to debian.map.fastlydns.net:80 (151.101.50.132). - connect (111: Connection refused) Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  Could not connect to debian.map.fastlydns.net:80 (151.101.50.132). - connect (111: Connection refused) Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bullseye-security/InRelease  Could not connect to debian.map.fastlydns.net:80 (151.101.50.132). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (151.101.66.132). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (151.101.130.132). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (151.101.194.132). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (151.101.2.132). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not connect to dl.google.com:80 (172.217.1.142). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Are you able to ping those mirrors from your local?

Comment: @memoricab yes local works completely fine

Comment: Wait, sorry, I think you are trying to build this image on Ubuntu server? Could you please try to ping those mirrors from your server?

Comment: I built your image and it has downloaded the gogole-chrome-stable fine.

Comment: @memoricab Yes, i have also tested it fine on my own VM, and on the server, just not from the docker container. Thanks for testing it out for me

Comment: I don't think anything wrong with Docker here. I think you should check server's settings.

Comment: @memoricab server is able to ping those mirrors and install google-chrome-stable fine. It's just not working when I try to build the docker container

Comment: Can you try as a single line like below and see.
`RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable`

Comment: @shivappa thanks for the input. I've resolved the error by using a totally new VM. Not sure why but the previous VM blocked repo pulls.